# Big Query view (table without duplicate rows)

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to create a view that is pretty much just like some table with some simple transformations and I want to make sure the values in a particular column are not duplicate.
So let's say the table looks like this:

```
ID, ColumnA, ColumnB
-------------------
1   cars     shirts
2   tvs      dogs
1   fingers  computers
```

And the resulting view would look like this:

```
ID, ColumnA, ColumnB
-------------------
1   cars     shirts
2   tvs      dogs
```

So, is there an equivalent to SELECT distint(ID), ColumnA, ColumnB?
What's the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: what would be the logic of selecting row with cars over the fingers?

Comment: I actually don't mind which one gets selected, as long as there is only one :)

Comment: That's ok. So see Elliott's answer than :o) while my answer still relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want an arbitrary row for each ID, use `ANY_VALUE`:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'cars' AS ColumnA, 'shirts' AS ColumnB UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ID, 'tvs' AS ColumnA, 'dogs' AS ColumnB UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 'fingers' AS ColumnA, 'computers' AS ColumnB
)
SELECT
  ANY_VALUE(t).*
FROM Input AS t
GROUP BY t.ID;
```

Or you can use the `ARRAY_AGG` trick to select the latest row based on a condition.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'cars' AS columnA, 'shirts' AS columnB UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'tvs', 'dogs' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'fingers', 'computers' 
)
SELECT r.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY columnA LIMIT 1)[OFFSET (0)] AS r
  FROM yourTable t
  GROUP BY id
)
-- ORDER BY id
```

Note: you should have some logic about selecting row with cars over the fingers! 
Above version (as an example) is based on asc order